# checked the radio button based on the ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax response, what i want is to check the radio button base on the sex value

```
//fetch_single.php
    {
        "l_name": "ASDF",
        "f_name": "FSDSD",
        "m_name": "F",
        "sex": "M",
    }
```

this is my radio button the male radio button is checked in default

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" value="M" checked> Male
<input class="form-check-input ml-1" type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" value="F"> Female
```

this is what i have tried

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
            $('#user_form').parsley().reset();
            var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url:"../controller/fetch_single.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{user_id:user_id},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                {
        $("input[name^='sex']").find('value="'+data.sex+'"').prop('checked',true);
                }
            })
        });
```

still no luck, im a beginner and im stuck on this thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find the radio button which have the matched value

```js
var data = {
  "l_name": "ASDF",
  "f_name": "FSDSD",
  "m_name": "F",
  "sex": "M",
}
$(document).on('click', '.update', function() {
  $("input[value='" + data.sex + "']").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" value="M" checked> Male
<input class="form-check-input ml-1" type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" value="F"> Female

<button class="update">Click</button>
```

Note: This is for reference for actual implementation `$("input[value='" + data.sex + "']").prop('checked', true);` need to be placed inside the `success` function

Comment: said cant accept answer in 7 minutes ill just update it after

Answer (score 1):

find only works in his child,match more attributes uses like this:

```
$('input[name^="sex"][value="'+data.sex+'"').prop('checked',true);
```