# display data in radio button and drop-down using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to display data in a form for updating the form :

so I'm using the following script :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){

          var id = $(this).attr('id');
         console.log(id);
           $('#form_result').html('');
          $.ajax({
          
             url:"castingss/"+id+"/edit",
           dataType:"json",
           type:"GET",
           success:function(html){
            $('#nom').val(html.data.nom);
            $('#prenom').val(html.data.prenom);
             $('#cine').val(html.data.cine);
            $('#fonction').val(html.data.fonction);
             $('#date_naissance').val(html.data.date_naissance);
            $('#lieu_naissance').val(html.data.lieu_naissance);
             $('#tel1').val(html.data.tel1);
            $('#tel2').val(html.data.tel2);

             $('#email').val(html.data.email);
             $('#store_image').html("<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + html.data.photo + " width='100' class='center'  />");
            $('#store_image').append("<input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' value='"+html.data.photo+"' />");

            $('#pays').val(html.data.pays.select);
             $('#ville').val(html.data.ville);
            $('#adresse').val(html.data.adresse);
             $('#qualification').val(html.data.qualification);
            $('#id_type_casting').val(html.data.id_type_casting);
             $('#id_type_facturation').val(html.data.id_type_facturation);
            $('#artiste').val(html.data.artiste);

            
            $('#hidden_id').val(html.data.id);
            $('.modal-title').text("Edit New Record");
            $('#action_button').val("Edit");
            $('#action').val("Edit");
            $('#formModal').modal('show');
           }
          })
         });
```

When I click on my button Edit I get the following result :

the data is displayed only in `text input`, but the inputs like `drop-down` and radion button I can't display the data or take the values ​​of these inputs

[image]

How can I display data in drop-down ana radio buttons

**Updated**

My Html :

```
<form id="castingform" method="post" action="castingss"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
       
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id_casting" />
                        <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" >
                             
                           </div> 
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_name">Prénom</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Prenom" >
                         
                           </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_cin">CIN</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cine" name="cine" placeholder="Cin">
                           </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="fonction">Fonction</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fonction" name="fonction" placeholder="Fonction">
                           </div>

                         </div>

                         <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_date_naissancee">Date de naissance</label>
                             <div class="input-group date">

                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_naissance" name="date_naissance">
                                            <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                                <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                            </span> 
                                        </div>
                                 </div>
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_lieu_naissance">Lieu de naissance</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lieu_naissance" name="lieu_naissance" placeholder="Lieu de naissance">
                           </div>
                         </div>  
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor-container" hidden>
                        <label for="guarantor">Nom et prénom du représentatnt légal </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_prenom" name="nom_prenom" placeholder="Représentant">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_identification_number-container" hidden>
                        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">CIN du représentatnt légal</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cine_representant" name="cine_representant" placeholder="CINE">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_lien-container" hidden>
                        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">Lien</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lien_casting" name="lien_casting" placeholder="Lien">
                    </div>    


                  <div class="form-row">
                         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                             <label for="">Téléphone 1</label>
                              </br>
                               <input type="tel" class="form-control"   id="tel1" name="tel1" placeholder="Téléphone 1" >
                        </div> 
                             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="tel2">Téléphone 2</label>
                                </br>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel2" name="tel2" placeholder="Téléphone 2" >
                           
                             </div>

                  </div>  

                     <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="email">Email</label>
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                           </div>
                            <!--  <div class="input-group mb-3"> -->
                               <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                               <label for="photo">Photo</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-file">
                               <input type="file" name="photo" class="custom-file-input" id="photo">
                               <label class="custom-file-label" for="casting_photo">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                          </br>
                           </br>

                             <div class=" col-md-6">
                          <span id="store_image" text-align: center></span>
                        </div>
                         </div>

                        
                          <!--   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="photo">Photo</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fonction" name="photo" placeholder="Fonction">
                           </div>
 -->
                         </div>
                       
                     
                         

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <label>Pays</label>
                           <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="pays" id="pays">
                             <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                             @foreach($countries as $country)
                           <option data-id="{{$country->id}}" value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                           </select>
                       </div>

                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <label>Ville</label>
                           <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="ville" id="ville">
                           </select>
                       </div>
                  </div>

                </br>

                     <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_name">Adresse</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adresse" name="adresse" placeholder="Adresse" >
                             
                           </div> 
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="qualification">Qualification</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control"         id="qualification" name="qualification" placeholder="Qualification" >
                         
                           </div>
                           </div>


                  <div class="form-row">
                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Type de casting</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="id_type_casting" id="id_type_casting">
                                        <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                                            <option value="1">Casting</option>
                                            <option value="2"> Influenceur</option>
                                                
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Type de facturation</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="id_type_facturation" id="id_type_facturation">
                                        <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                                            <option value="1">Facture</option>
                                            <option value="2">Facture Auto-Entrepreneur</option>
                                              <option value="3">Contrat</option>    
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                        
                           </div>
</br>
                      <div class="form-row">
                         <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <label for="artiste">Artiste</label>
                              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio"  name="artiste"  id="artiste" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="artiste">Oui</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                  <input type="radio"  name="artiste" id="artisten" class="custom-control-input"  value="0">
                                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="artisten" >Non</label>
                              </div>
                           </div>


                    </div>
  </br>
                          
  </br>


                        <div class="form-group" align="center">
                          <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
                          <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="ADD" />
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-md-6">
                          <span id="form_result"></span>
                        </div>
                     </form>
```

**UPDATED2**

Output of html :

```
{data: {…}}
data:
actif: 1
adresse: "N° 40 RUE PALESxxxxxx"
artiste: 1
cine: "125mjj"
created_at: "2021-06-15T22:27:31.000000Z"
date_naissance: "1989-06-16"
email: "xxxxxxx33@gmail.com"
fonction: "hhhhhh"
id_casting: 7
id_representant: null
id_type_casting: 2
id_type_facturation: 3
lieu_naissance: "CASA"
mineur: 0
nom: "xxxxxxxxxx"
pays: "Andorra"
photo: "1977941556.jpg"
prenom: "xxxxxx"
qualification: "sdfghjbk"
tel1: "0631798367"
tel2: "0662039671"
updated_at: "2021-06-15T22:27:31.000000Z"
ville: "Les Escaldes"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

If you have any idea help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, show your html code as well response from ajax call i.e : output of `html` .

Comment: @Swati , Thank you for your reply, check my Update please

Comment: output of html . Do , `console.log(html)` inside success function of ajax .

Comment: check , my post

Comment: for the id_representant, it is null, because it is a foreign key, and I should display the data associated to this id if the age is less than 18

Comment: which values refer to select-box and radio ? Also, you radio name should be same else user can select both radio

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233822/discussion-between-swati-and-ha-jar).

Comment: this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604856/checked-the-radio-button-based-on-the-ajax-response)
worked for me like a charm